# Setting background color apply on part of screen

Tags: ios, swift

I am using swift to set background color to viewController:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

But part of the screen is still painted in white why is that?

Comment: try checking the view frame, may be the view is not covering the whole window

Comment: some other subview will be having white color

Comment: Post a screenshot from your Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have assigned your Class (.swift file) to your ViewController in Storyboard.

double check in storyboard you not have added any View to whole screen(controller).

Answer (score 0):

check this way, it will show if there are any hidden views.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There could be another view on top of it, i.e this view could be hidden behind another view, and changing color of main view won't be visible to you.